# removing duplicates from a file from starting point of a file

Tags: duplicates

**input file**

```
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
f
e
```

I tried below options:

```
awk '!x[$0]++' file.txt > file.txt.tmp && mv file.txt.tmp file.txt

perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' file.txt > file.txt.tmp && mv file.txt.tmp file.txt
awk '{if (++dup[$0] == 1) print $0;}' file.txt > file.txt.tmp && mv file.txt.tmp file.txt
```

But it removes duplicates and gives output like below:

```
a
b
c
d
f
e
```

But we need output something like below.

**Output file**

```
 d
 a
 b
 c
 f
 e
```

Comment: consider this                                                                                             option1 perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' file.txt > file.txt.tmp && mv file.txt.tmp file.txt             option 2   awk '{if (++dup[$0] == 1) print $0;}' file.txt > file.txt.tmp && mv file.txt.tmp file.txt

Answer (score 0):

**I got the answer as below.**

awk -F'|' '{k=$1 FS $2} NR==FNR {A[k]=NR; next} A[k]==FNR' file.txt file.txt